# Help to translate Chinese Calligraphy

Tags: calligraphy

I recently purchased this scroll from an auction, can anyone translate what is says please?  Thank you in advance for reading.[image]

Comment: It is Japanese, try asking Japanese SE

Comment: Japanese? It is 中國草書.

Comment: First one looks like 於 last one looks like 舞  some ”法尘“  ”学“ in the middle but yeah it is too hard for me lol

Comment: I said it was Japanese because I saw お and も. Can it be Japanese 草書? Japanese use a lot of Chinese characters (Kanji) too

Comment: I am with tang ho on this one.  There are some chinese heavy cursive that can look similar to japanese kana, but with mutliple in one couplet I think Japanese heavy cursive is way more likely.